# What happens if you don't close an ODBC connection?

Tags: odbc, ado

I've seen other posts about using PHP and ADO to access ODBC databases, but I don't think my question has been asked outside of PHP.  I've recently taken over a project where a touchscreen interface is running Windows XP and using some proprietary european programming language that's extremely similar to Java to interface with PLCs and machinery.

We record information from various sensors at a regular interval, and then use the program to open a connection to an ODBC database and store the records.  I've been tasked with tracking down a bug wherein data just stops recording for days at a time for no apparent reason, and I'm convinced it has something to do with either the ODBC database (fixable) or a version incompatibility between windows and the PLCs (not fixable).  So I'm shooting for the fixable one first.

The program creates a new ActiveXObject and uses ADO to open a connection to the database, strings together a command, executes it, and then closes the connection.  It does all this each time a record is created, and I'm trying to find out if there's a reason the original programmers do it this way instead of creating an adodb.Connection, opening it, and then making a transaction for each data record to write, and closing it only when the user quite the program.

The only thing I can think of is that they were worried about what would happen if the touchscreen lost power while a connection was open.  What would that do?  Nobody really knows anything about this almost-Java-language that we're using, so I can't say for sure what happens to ActiveXObjects when the program closes.  Could something like this be causing these few-day-long lapses in recording, or am I totally barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opening and closing the connection each time it is needed would normally be considered the safer and the least network intense approach. The only time it is inefficient is when many calls are being made to the database in without much time elapsing between them.

Leaving database connections open is sometimes not recommended. In the case where you are using a file-based database such as Visual Foxpro or MS Access, a database file can actually become corrupt by a network connection being dropped although I think normally for this to happen the connection would need to drop during a write of some kind.

Do you have any error control or debugging options? Could you write to a text file each time a call is attempted to the database?

I really don't think the language being used here is overly important since you are using ADO, ODBC, and I'm assuming some kind of standard database format. The failure probably lies with one of these technologies, unless there is an error somewhere in your code that is preventing the data logging routine from firing.